# Oracle constraints not enabled

Tags: oracle

In one of my Oracle databases, I tried to enable some constraints on a particular table. It shows that the table is altered and no error is showed.
When I query all_constraints, the constraint is disabled. I tried this several times but i got the same issue. On another database it's working fine. It sounds weird to me.

Comment: Please show us the code.

Comment: Also, post database version (all digits, please; for example, 11.2.0.4.0).

Comment: Please show us the columns status, deferrable, deferred, validated and rely of all_constraints.

Comment: Also, as you are looking at the `all_` view, are you sure you're looking at the right objects - maybe you have the same objects in multiple schemas, and you're seeing a different owner's disabled constraints?

Comment: Sorry guys I was busy with other urgent stuff! our DBA has fixed the issue. Apprently there was an issue with the Oracle client editor that one of our team member was using. It shows some funny stuff !!!  Thanks a lot for your prompt response and help!! Appreciaite!